# What is -w in a Perl shebang line?

Tags: perl

I have been seeing this

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl -w
```

in some of the perl scripts. I would like to know what does this `-w` stands for.

Comment: run `perl -help` to see it yourself.

Comment: `http://perlmeme.org/faqs/perl_thinking/warnings.html`

Comment: `man perlrun` is another source of wisdom.

Comment: As you'll see in the recommended documentation, turning on `warnings` (what `-w` does) is better done by [warnings pragma](https://perldoc.perl.org/warnings). That is what you _always_ must have in your code, along with the `use strict;`.  So see [strict pragma](https://perldoc.perl.org/strict) as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [perlrun](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun) docs show all of the command-line options. `-w` enables global warnings.

However, that's a legacy feature. Modern code uses the [warnings](https://perldoc.perl.org/warnings) pragma to enable warnings only in the current scope:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
```